# Azure portal monitor showing code result 500 for a succeeded operation

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureportal

I have succeed to implement one Azure Function triggered with Http and implemented in .net. The execution succeeds ( I can see the results in my database ), no errors in AppInsights, in the monitor in Azure portal, I can see that the operation succeeds but I don't know why the code result is 500 and not 200 ? The function is in .net core targeting .net 4.7.1 and is Async.

[image: Azure portal screenshot]

My function code :

```
public static class SingleTaskProcessorFunction
{
    static SingleTaskProcessorFunction()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += AzureFunctionsResolveAssembly.CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
        SingleTaskProcessorFunction_Internal.Init();
    }
    [FunctionName("SingleTaskProcessor")]
    public static Task Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req)
    {
        return new SingleTaskProcessorFunction_Internal().Run(req);
    }
}
```

The body of my function has only one line because I need to resolve the path to all the referenced assemblies ( to solve another bug in Function Runtime ). My function is Async, I can put async in the signature and await for the .Run(), it will still put Operation Succeeded with Code results 500.

Comment: could you share some code ? also from the screenshot, I can see 536 errors. Btw I didn't know that you can have azure portal in french :-)

Comment: I think the language depends on the user location because I have my browser and system in english :). Those errors has been there from my first tests and they were  500 internal server errors which is correct. I'll share my code